# Opaning a control port on Tor [SOLVED]

Tags: connection

I am trying to open a control port on tor with the following command:

```
sudo -u debian-tor tor --CookieAuthentication 0  --ControlPort 9050 --SocksPort 50001
```

but it will only stay open for 5 or so seconds before closing.  Is there any way to fix this?
Logs (these are from when I first run the command):

```
Jan 02 18:37:54.600 [notice] Tor 0.3.5.12 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1d, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4, and Libzstd 1.3.8.
Jan 02 18:37:54.600 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Jan 02 18:37:54.601 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jan 02 18:37:54.611 [warn] Linelist option '__HashedControlSessionPassword' has no value. Skipping.
Jan 02 18:37:54.612 [warn] ControlPort is open, but no authentication method has been configured.  This means that any program on your computer can reconfigure your Tor.  That's bad!  You should upgrade your Tor controller as soon as possible.
Jan 02 18:37:54.619 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:50001
Jan 02 18:37:54.619 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:50001
Jan 02 18:37:54.619 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Jan 02 18:37:54.619 [notice] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
```

torrc file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/inyourface34456/torrc-file/main/torrc
(i could not paste it in. i had to upload it to github)

Comment: Can you post the logs? It's probably because one of the ports is already in use.

Comment: So tor exits immediately after those messages? Can you post your torrc file, and also run `echo $?` after tor exits? Do you have `RunAsDaemon` set anywhere?

Comment: no, it exits in about 5 or so seconds after exacuting

Comment: @Steve echo $? returns 1 and RunAsDaemon is set to 1

Comment: With `RunAsDaemon 1`, this behaviour (exiting after address binding) is expected. Can you check for tor processes running using `ps aux | grep -i tor`? There is likely a tor process running in the background.

Comment: it seems that when enabling control port in torrc file, I just get a warning saying that tor is a socks proxy, not HTTPS proxy

Comment: You should ask a new question for that, and add details about what you're doing when you get that message.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that `RunAsDaemon` was enabled in the torrc, which moves tor to the background once it has finished binding any listening sockets. You can find the background tor process using `ps aux | grep -i tor`.